# shell script problem

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script

Create a shell script  which
tests if a file  does exist. If yes, it will echo removing file with timestamp of the form YYYYMMDD-HH:MM:SS log of the date command and remove file and reschedules itself to run 5 minutes later using at command

```
if (( test -f /tmp/norun ))
then
    echo " removing /tmp/norun" 'data +%Y%m%d-%T'>>s30928290.log
    #rm /tmp/norun
    #timesh='date --date="1 minute"
    at -f /home/s300928290/s300928290.at now + 5 miniutes
else
    echo "hello world"  'data +%Y%m%d-%T'>>s30928290.log
fi
#echo "none";
```

I can not run this script. Anyone know why?

Comment: Is your script really spaced like that?  What error do you get when you run it?

Comment: Could you edit your post and paste the code in plain text ASCII, please? The way it's presented now, it's more or less unreadable.  Also mention what happens when your run it. There's at least one syntax error on the first line (`((` and `))` should be `[[` and `]]`), and later some unmatched backticks, I think (but it's hard to read).

Comment: What do you mean that you cannot run it? Are you missing a computer? What happens when you try to run it?

Comment: I sorted out the character encoding issues. Please edit it again if it's not correct. I had to break some lines manually.

Comment: The current phrasing sounds more like a directive than a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have modified your script to the following:

```
if [[ -f /tmp/norun ]]; then
    echo "Removing /tmp/norun $(date '+%Y%m%d-%T')" >>s30928290.log
    rm -- /tmp/norun
    timesh=$(date --date='1 minute') # This variable is not being used
    at -f /home/s300928290/s300928290.at now + 5 minutes
else
    echo "Hello, world $(date '+%Y%m%d-%T')" >>s30928290.log
fi
```

As Kusalananda pointed out `(( ... ))` is a bash arithmetic expression and not valid for a file test, so it has been modified to `[[ ... ]]`.

You have `data` when I believe you wanted `date`.  Also these need to be put in command substitution ( `$( ... )` ).

Additionally you had spelled `minutes` incorrectly in your `at` command

Comment: @user66, did this answer solved your problem? If yes, accept his answer.

Comment: i got line 9 : date +%Y%m%d-%T command not found